# Convert My SQL database to MS SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, converters

I wanted to know if there is a way to convert a .sql file (My SQL backup) to .bak file (MS SQL backup)?

I am currently using MS SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005

Comment: Unfortunaly ive spent the past 2 days trying to figure something out and all i get are softwares that require access to the database itself (server, username, password).  But i have only the backup file (.sql)

Comment: Okay; perhaps in that case it's worth installing a MySQL server from which you can load the `.sql` backup file?  It is, after all, free and takes around 5 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Not really. An almost easy way to accomplish this is below.

- Install a MySQL server and restore the .sql into it.
- Then in your SQL Server create a linked server to the MySQL server.
- You can then select the tables in the MySQL server over to SQL Server with something  similar to below.

  SELECT *
  INTO [TABLENAME]
  FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVERNAME], 'SELECT * FROM MYSQLTABLENAME')
- Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA on the MySQL server, dynamic SQL, variables and a cursor you can loop through all the tables without coding for each table.
- Don't forget to turn off the temporary MySQL instance. It only needs to be on while you're restoring/extracting from it.
- And since *.bak are proprietary you have to create that once you've pulled all the tables into the SQL Server DB. Not sure if you really needed the BK or just the SQL Server Database.

While this may sound painful you're really talking less the 50 lines of code. Also, SQL Server will mostly handle the typing for you.